# Selenium (Nunit) with MTM (Microsoft Test Manager)

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, mtm

I want to perform automated test with Selenium,Nunit,TFS and MTM.

As i'm trying to find a way to run my selenium code using Nunit with MTM, i've searched alot regarding this but didn't find required solution as most of the people gave solution using MStest not with nunit after this i want to see my test case result on MTM.

Answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In an Microsoft Environment, why would you stick to NUnit for UI-Tests? There is not one advantage using it. If you need in-code-declared parametrized tests you can use MSTest V2 with `DataTestMethod` attribute. Anyway, if you still stick to incompatible non-MSTest approach and want to see your results in Team Services (MTM is just a GUI for it), then you need to create a test run and publish it. This is done using either the TFS API (in a little C# program for instance) or using the `tcm.exe run /publish` command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience (lots of trial and error), you can only Associate Automation with an MSTest Test Method, to test cases in MTM.

A solution I've used with Selenium, NUnit and TFS is to use the VNext builds to run my tests, and use the build status to track the test results (including widgets on the dashboard).